# Node.js express request staying alive

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am working on a REST API in node with express. I use the following to get a list of accounts (temporarily reading the responses from file)

```
app.get('/accounts/list', function(req, res){
  var filename = basepath 
    + 'accounts-list.xml';
  var cb = function(input){send_successful_response(res, input);};
  var cb_err = function(input){send_error_response(res, input);};
  response_for_file(filename, cb, cb_err);
});
```

With:

```
function response_for_file(filename, cb_success, cb_error){
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(error, data){
    if (!error) return cb_success(data)
    else return cb_error(error)
  });
}
```

and:

```
function send_successful_response(res, content){
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    .status(200)
    .send(content);
}
```

When I call this route in Chrome all looks fine. However when I call it from a REST console, it seems to stay alive. I wonder if there is anything required to show the response should be terminated, or if this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realized the issue was that node set's access control limitations. Adding the following resolved the issue:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.get('Origin')) return next();
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age', -1);
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) return res.send(200);
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call `end()` on `res`?

Also, it is better to [createReadStream()](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) from the file and `pipe()` it to `res`.